# name 'CONNECTION' not declared

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then

            For i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If ListView1.Items(i).Checked = True Then

                    strSQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_hbill WHERE ID = '" & ListView1.Items(i).Text & "'"
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, CONNECTION)
                    da.Fill(ds)

                End If
            Next i
        End If
        List()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure that you have **Connection** variable

like this

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

   Dim CONNECTION As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
   CONNECTION.ConnectionString = "connectionstring"
   CONNECTION.Open()

        If ListView1.Items.Count > 0 Then

            For i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                If ListView1.Items(i).Checked = True Then

                    strSQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_hbill WHERE ID = '" & ListView1.Items(i).Text & "'"
                    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, CONNECTION)
                    da.Fill(ds)

                End If
            Next i
        End If
        List()
End Sub
```

[connectionstring](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: How to have this?  ------>  'Public CONNECTION As MySql.data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'

Comment: Just Declare it in after the class name decleration